Any Protocol type casting always failing
I have a class that conforms to a protocol. But it always fail when I try to cast or verify if it conforms to the protocol.
typealias DeviceHandler = (any Device) -> Void

protocol Device {
    var name: String { get }
}

class DevicesViewModel<T: Device> {
    var devices = [T]()

    func findDevices() {
        DevicesManager.findDevices() { device in
            // casting is failing
            // even if I do device is T, it fails
            guard let device = device as? T else { return }

            self.devices.append(device)
        }
    }
}

class DevicesManager {

    static func findDevices(completion: @escaping DeviceHandler) {
        completion(Computer(name: "Macbook"))
    }
}

class Computer: NSObject, Device {

    var name: String

    init(name: String) {
        self.name = name
        
        super.init()
    }
}


You are trying to append an unknown Device ('aka' any Device) to an array with a known Device element type('aka' T: Device) which is not possible.
Try to make the array accept unknown devices like:
class DevicesViewModel {
    var devices = [Device]() // 

    func findDevices() {
        DevicesManager.findDevices() { device in
            self.devices.append(device)
        }
    }
}

P.S: You didn't need the generic T type in the first place.
